# Craps game problem, ignoring if statement

Tags: c++

I'm currently in a class that wants me to make a craps game.

The problem is in int main on the second while statement comparing the point with the roll.  It ignores the if statement and does the loop again, even though it hits the point or 7. Sometimes it works like it should and other times it repeats the loop a few times.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int diceRoll() {

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    x = rand() % 6 + 1;
    y = rand() % 6 + 1;

    cout << "You rolled a " << x << " and a " << y << " which comes out to ------> " << x + y << " <-------" << endl;

    return x + y;
}

bool playAgain() {
    char ans;
    cout << "Do you want to play again ?? Y to continue, N to quit." << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    while (ans != 'Y' || ans != 'y' || ans != 'n' || ans != 'N') {
        if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (ans == 'N' || ans == 'n')
        {
            return false;
        }       
        cout << "Do you want to play again ?? Y to continue, N to quit." << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dices, bid, point = 0;
    int money = 50;
    bool gameRunning = true;
    bool didTheyWin;

    while (gameRunning == true) {
        if (money == 0) {
            cout << "You have no money, ending game." << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Please enter a bid. You currently have $" << money << endl;
        cout << "$";
        cin >> bid;

        while (bid > money) {
            cout << "Please bet below your current balance: $" << money << endl;
            cout << "$";
            cin >> bid;
        }

        dices = diceRoll();
        didTheyWin = false;
        if ((dices == 7) || (dices == 11)) {
            cout << "You won $" << bid << " !" << endl;
            money = money + bid;
        }
        else if ((dices == 2) || (dices == 3) || (dices == 12)) {
            cout << "You LOSE! You lost $" << bid << " !" << endl;
            money = money - bid;
        }
        else  {
            point = dices;
            cout << "The target number is > " << point << " <" << endl;
            cout << "If you hit a 7 you lose, if you hit the target you win. \nYou automatically roll until one of these two things happen.\n";
            while (didTheyWin == false) {
                diceRoll();
                dices = diceRoll();
                if (dices == point) {
                    cout << "You won $" << bid << " !" << endl;
                    money = money + bid;
                    cout << "You now have $" << money << endl;
                    didTheyWin = true;
                }
                else if (dices == 7) {
                    cout << "You LOSE! You lost $" << bid << " !" << endl;
                    money = money - bid;
                    cout << "You now have $" << money << endl;
                    didTheyWin = true;
                }
            }
        }
        gameRunning = playAgain();
    }

    cout << "Thanks for playing. _END_" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that people can compile and test themselves.

Comment: `ans != 'Y' || ans != 'y'` is always true.

Comment: Sorry first time posting, thought i could just post a section of it.

Comment: You're supposed to post neither a section nor the whole thing; you should post a [mcve].

Comment: testx3, what you are expected to do is reduce your program down to the minimum code required to demonstrate the error you want help with. This should result in a complete program that is about 5 lines long. As an added bonus, once all of the unnecessary code is gone, you'll probably see the bug and how to fix it yourself, rendering the question pointless. If you are asking a question and have not already produced a MCVE or something similar, you are asking the question too soon and should do more debugging.

Comment: Btw; the quality of numbers returned by `rand()` is often not optimal. Also, your use of modulo is introducing bias in the result. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random and https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful for ways to improve.

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code. Then you would find your error by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You call `diceRoll` twice, and ignore what you get back from the first call.  You'll see the results of that first roll displayed, but they'll be ignored and you'll roll again.